Sorting the List using two conditions
I have a bit of a problem with sorting. I have a Person class that contains, among other things, two parameters: the age and the birth time:
public class Person {
int age; 
private final Instant birthTime;

I want to write sorting logic that sorts the list of people by number of years, and if the number of years is the same, sorts by date of birth. I wrote such logic:
return people.stream().sorted((p1, p2) -> {
        if (p1.getAge() != p2.getAge()) {
            return Integer.compare(p2.getAge(), p1.getAge());
        } else {
            return p2.birthTime().compareTo(p1.birthTime());
        }
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

But I think this is not a correct implementation, I wonder what will happen if two people are born at the same time. Can anyone suggest a better solution?

I wonder what will happen if two people are born at the same time - what are the business requirements?

better solution - better how?

"If two people are born at the same time", it is sorted by age. Right?

Seems to me that a person's age is derived from their date (or time) of birth.  So you only need to order by birth date.  So that would be a better solution.

You could also encode the logic for comparing Person object as a Comparator<Person> which you declare separately.  Whether that is "better" depends on your "goodness" criteria ... and ultimately your personal opinion.

I want to write sorting logic that sorts the list of people by number of years, and if the number of years is the same, sorts by date of birth. That would already happen were you to sort on birthTime. You can remove the redundant (the age is contained in birthtime) age

You can of course have a getAge helper method. This could be its body: return Period.between(LocalDate.ofInstant(birthTime, ZoneId.systemDefault()), LocalDate.now()).getYears(); No room for error between two values that are meant to be directly related now

Presuming you were using a record for the Person class and a List<Person> you could do it like this.
Streaming is not necessary since the List interface has a sort method. But there is nothing wrong with the way you are doing it.  The sort method you are using is a stable sort so if all tests are equal the two People under test will be kept in their same relative order.
record Person(int age, Instant birthTime) {
}

List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>(); // eventually populated.

Comparator<Person> comp = Comparator.comparing(Person::age)
                .thenComparing(Person::birthTime).reversed();
people.sort(comp);

Both of the fields on which you are sorting are naturally sorted in ascending order.  It looks like you want them to be sorted in descending order.  Specifying reverse() reverses each test in each preceding comparator to do just that.
